# Excel like filtering with react-data-grid and primereact multiselect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, react-data-grid, primereact

I'm trying to add excel like filtering to [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid)(v7) with [primereact multiselect](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/multiselect) and running into some problems with the dropdown closing. By excel like filtering I mean when you apply a filter that updates all the other filters options instead of keeping the total options always. Here is a [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-field-o0ov7?file=/src/App.js) that shows the problem ([here is the example it was based off](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/stories/demos/HeaderFilters.tsx)). In the sandbox I have a button that controls if the filters pull from `rows` or `filteredRows`. You can see that when the button says `rows` it works but that wont filter the dropdowns since it's using the whole dataset. When the button says `filteredRows` that filters the dropdowns but then also closes the dropdown on change.

Also you would notice this kind of makes a multiselect useless since the current filter your on will always be filtered down to the 1 option you picked. So the current filter being changed should not change options but all the others filter options should change.

To sum it up:

- I want the dropdown to stay open even when any dropdown options
  change
- The current filter being changed should not change options but all
  the others filter options should change.

I think the problem has to do with `columns` re-rendering when using `filteredRows` vs `rows`.